# Is there a way to add a custom IDResolver in Jakarta 3 with Java 11?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, java-11

I'm in the process of migrating a number of libraries from Java 8 to Java 11. I've found lots of great resources for help on most of my questions but not this particular one.

I use a custom `IDResolver` in Java 8 to allow me to split data between multiple files or allow existing in-memory objects to be considered for ID resolution. Has anyone done something similar using Jakarta?

Comment: What is exactly `IDResolver`? Let's make your question clear and informationally.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/toplink/java-reference/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/IDResolver.html

The IDResolver is what JAXB uses to map an ID to a particular object.